# Where do class 2 preservatives end up after digestion?

Tags: biochemistry, digestion

Do anybody know what happens to class 2 preservatives in general after they are digested - i.e details like weather they are absorbed into blood as simplest elements or excreted out or assimilated to a part of the body. If the question is oversimplified, please tell where sodium propionate or any other convenient ones eventually end up at.